# Sanitation Options (Hard Liquor)

Tags: brewing

The first time I made a batch of beer, the guy said that you could use wine sanitize to clean the bottles (you can't - beer sanitizer kills more stuff than wine sanitizer). My resulting beer was soapy-tasting and cloudy. After that, I used a bleach solution and the next batch came out way better.

At the local homebrewer's club, I've heard people talk about using hard liquor (e.g. cheap whiskey or vodka) to sanitize equipment, because they seem to think that other sanitizers affect the end taste.

Has anyone used hard liquor to sanitize? Does it make a difference to the taste? Does it work well?

Comment: While this is an EXCELLENT question, you should post is to homebrew.stackexchange.com, where all questions about the process of brewing beer, especially sanitation, are addressed.

Comment: This belongs on homebrew.stackexchange.com, as it is really about the homebrew process.

Comment: Definitely to ask on homebrew.  I will say quickly that I got my techniques from a professional winemaker and I typically use hot water.  This is, however, very tricky and carries risks of burns.  Post a link to the question on homebrew and I will fully answer there.